# implode a key with a value

Tags: php, arrays, implode

How do I implode 2 values, 1 as the key and the other as the value. Say I have:

```
$string = 'hello_world';

$arg = explode('_', $string);
```

I now have `$arg[0]` and `$arg[1]` (as you know)

How can I implode that so it becomes this structure

```
Array (
    'hello' => 'world'
)
```

Comment: Manually, there is no such magic function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array($arg[0] => $arg[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fun way to do it without using intermediate args ;)

```
$string = "hello_world";
$result = call_user_func_array( "array_combine", array_chunk( explode("_", $string ), 1 ));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something this obvious:

```
$arg = explode('_', 'hello_world');
print_r(array($arg[0] => $arg[1]));
```

I assume it's a bit more complicated than this. Maybe the string contains multiple of these things. ex: 'hello_world,foo_bar,stack_overflow'. In which case you'd need to explode by the comma first:

```
$args = explode(',', 'hello_world,foo_bar,stack_overflow');
$parsed = array();

foreach($args as $arg) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('_', $arg);
    $parsed[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Nah it was that 'obvious', we all have those moments haha.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'hello_world';
$arg = explode('_', $string);
$array = array($arg[0] => $arg[1]);
```

would be the quickest way